# ExtJS 5.0 - assistance with overrides

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, overriding

In an existing ExtJS 5.0 project, cannot change the original code. We **are** allowed to add code to an existing `overrides/` directory.

I have an existing function `generateTree` in class `Products.view.ProductsTreeViewController` that I want to override.

The current function is in file `PTVC.js` under `Useless/app/view/`.

This is the code I'm using to override:

```
Ext.define('overrides.Products.view.ProductsTreeViewController', {
    override :'Products.view.ProductsTreeViewController',
    generateTree: function (data) {
        if (this.isValid(data))
            this.callOverridden(data);
        else
           this.callOverridden(this.getDefaultData());
    }
};
```

> First question, where should the code reside under `overrides/`? I've seen many different configurations suggested, e.g.

*Everything in one file:*

```
Useless/
    overrides/
        app.js
```

*Same path as original file:*

```
Useless/
    overrides/
        app/
            view/
                PTVC.js
```

*Overridden class name:*

```
Useless/
    overrides/
        Products/
            view/
                ProductsTreeViewController/
                    class.js
```

I've tried all of the above and many more approaches and confirmed through various means that the code does **not** get included!

> So second question, how to make sure it is included?

The documentation makes it seem like it's so easy, which makes it all the more frustrating.

In the version I'm using there is no `classpath` variable in `sencha.cfg`, in any case I'd be changing an existing file, so likely can't do that, or add `requires` in `Ext.application` for the same reason.

> So third question, in lieu of modifying existing files, is there a build command line switch I can use to specify an additional build directory?

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. Any advice, short of quitting my job, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's best to duplicate the directory structure, then you don't have to worry about file name collisions, but you can put the files anywhere under `overrides/`.
2. Are you running ExtJS 5.0.0? It has a regression bug whereby they forgot to include `"overrides": "${app.dir}/overrides"` in `app.json`. You can also modify a config file under `.sencha` but it's better to have it in `app.json`. You won't need `requires`. This is fixed in version 5.0.1.
3. Probably not, but it's a really small change to add that line in `app.json` and the only way to make overrides work in 5.0.0 (which I suspect you're using).

Comment: Yes, I am using 5.0.0. That's exactly what the issue was!